# Use shell script to execute java saxon transform to create file

Tags: java, php, shell, xslt, saxon

I've been trying to use PHP to execute a shell script(`.sh`) and do Java saxon.transform to create a file. When I run the PHP file, it doesn't show any errors but the file is not being created.

`script.sh` is executable(`chmod +x`), and `jar` path is predefined.

### script.sh

```
echo "Running step 01."
java net.sf.saxon.Transform -o:review.html -s:merged.html -xsl:xsls/01-simplify.xsl --suppressXsltNamespaceCheck:on;

if [ -f "review.html" ]
then
    echo "Review.html file successfully generated."
    echo "Done"
else
    echo "Something went wrong."
    echo "Check the <code>merged.html</code> file."
fi
```

### php

```
echo shell_exec('./script.sh');
```

### Result

```
Something went wrong.
Check the merged.html file.
```

The same java command works as it's supposed to when executed from command line. It just doesn't work on web.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, with PHP7.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check your error.log file it should give you more details as to what is going wrong. using the command:

> tail /var/log/apache2/error.log -n 100

Or similar

I tried running a similar shell script within a php environment. I get the following error:

> Error on line 7 of test.xsl:
>     Failed to create output file file:/var/www/html/samples/review.html: Permission denied
>     in built-in template rule
>   Failed to create output file file:/var/www/html/samples/review.html

It is probably permission problems  you are getting when you create the output file.